# Entity Framework 5 Function Import with Spatial Data

Tags: stored-procedures, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I am creating a model from an existing DB using EF5 with a table containing a geography column. The model for the table works perfectly fine. However if I try to map a stored procedure which simply selects the geography column I cannot map this column in a Function Import. In the Column Information the EDM Type is set to "Not Supported". However the model maps the geography type as a parameter without a problem.

IDE is VS2012 Premium, framework .NET4.5

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oké, so I found one way to answer this myself. To anyone interested: I've manually created a new Scalar Property of the Geography type on the complex type which results from the SP. Now somehow the value maps. Looks to me the editor is not able to create a property, but mapping an existing property is no problem. To me this seems like a bug in the editor.

Also have a look at this thread: [Build error when using VS 11, .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792558/build-error-when-using-vs-11-net-4-5-and-entity-framework)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating the complex type without the my geography column through function import and afterwards added the scalar property of type Geography.  Though it wouldn't automatically map the column for me.  So I looked through EDMX with the XML editor looking for the mapping details for the function and added the mapping information manually.  After that everything worked fine.